# iterated function $a(n) = \lfloor n\phi + 0.5\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, golden-ratio

Let $a(n) = \lfloor n\phi + 0.5\rfloor$ for all $n \geqslant 1$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Now let

$$a(n)^k = a(a(\ldots(a(n))))$$

where we have iterated $a(n)$, $k$ times in the RHS. I am looking for a nice closed form of $a(n)^k$. I am working on this problem for a long time but didn't get any satisfactory solution. Indeed, I was also able to find some sort of closed form but it again seems to be very painful to evaluate for some large $n$. I'm rather looking for a nice closed form.

I highhly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks.

Comment: It could be useful you give the first terms of the sequence for $n=1$, $n=2$ and a few other.

Comment: I think the problem is more or less clear? why do you need the initial values?

Comment: just to see if some patterns appear

Comment: Because with [initial values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%281%2F2+%2B+n*%281%2Bsqrt%285%29%29%2F2%29+for+n+from+1+to+25), you can find your sequence [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+6%2C+8%2C+10%2C+11%2C+13%2C+15%2C+16%2C+18%2C+19%2C+21%2C+23%2C+24%2C+26%2C+28%2C+29%2C+31%2C+32%2C+34%2C+36%2C+37%2C+39%2C+40&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: So, this is [A007067](https://oeis.org/A007067), known to satisfy $a(a(n))=a(n)+n$, a result from 2006.

Comment: How do you prove that $a(a(n)) = a(n) + n$?

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comments, a proof of $a(a(n))=a(n)+n$.

---

> **Proposition 1.** $\left\lfloor \frac{a(n)}{\phi} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=n$

[Given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties) $x-1< \lfloor x\rfloor \leq x$, we have
$$n\phi - \frac{1}{2} <a(n)\leq n\phi + \frac{1}{2} \iff\\
n-\frac{1}{2\phi} <\frac{a(n)}{\phi}\leq n+\frac{1}{2\phi} \iff\\
n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\phi} <\frac{a(n)}{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}\leq n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\phi}$$

[Given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Calculation) $1+\frac{1}{\phi}=\phi$ and $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\phi}>0$, then
$$n<n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\phi} <\frac{a(n)}{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}\leq n+\frac{\phi}{2}<n+1$$

or
$$n<\frac{a(n)}{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}<n+1 \Rightarrow 
\left\lfloor \frac{a(n)}{\phi} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=n$$

---

> **Proposition 2.** $a(a(n))=a(n)+n$.

Obviously $a(n)\in\mathbb{N}$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences)
$$a(a(n))= \left\lfloor a(n)\phi + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=
\left\lfloor a(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{\phi}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=\\
a(n)+\left\lfloor \frac{a(n)}{\phi} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor = ...$$
applying **Proposition 1**
$$...= a(n)+n$$

---

[Now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)
$$a^{\circ 2}(n)=a(a(n))=F_2\cdot a(n) + F_1\cdot n$$
$$a^{\circ 3}(n)=a(a(\color{red}{a(n)}))=a(\color{red}{a(n)})+\color{red}{a(n)}=2\cdot a(n)+n=F_3\cdot a(n) + F_2\cdot n$$
$$a^{\circ 4}(n)=a(a(a(\color{blue}{a(n)})))=2\cdot a(\color{blue}{a(n)})+\color{blue}{a(n)}=3\cdot a(n)+2n=F_4\cdot a(n) + F_3\cdot n$$

---

By induction, this is
$$a^{\circ k}(n)=F_k\cdot a(n) + F_{k-1}\cdot n \tag{1}$$
because
$$a^{\circ (k+1)}(n)=a^{\circ k}(a(n))=F_k\cdot a(a(n)) + F_{k-1}\cdot a(n)=\\
(F_k+F_{k-1})\cdot a(n) + F_{k}\cdot n=F_{k+1}\cdot a(n) + F_{k}\cdot n$$